# php-fpm said "failed to post process the configuration"

Tags: php, nginx

I build php 5.3.5 with FPM, but when I trien to started the php-fpm daemon this way :

`sudo /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm start`

nothing happens (the programs show me the help)

and when I did this

sudo /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -t

```
 Jan 25 09:54:59.634168 [ALERT] [pool www] pm.min_spare_servers(0) must be a positive value
```

`Jan 25 09:54:59.634293 [ERROR] failed to post process the configuration`

Any clue? I need to make this php work with nginx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of help do you receive?

You should set `pm.min_spare_servers` to something like `pm.min_spare_servers = 5`

Also check `pm.max_spare_servers` in php-fpm.conf

Comment: The program print the "usage" message

Comment: you mean something like:
Usage: php-fpm [ flags ] < options >

Normal Options:
    start stop restart pause zap
      Default init.d options.
...?
try to:
'sudo bash'
then:
'/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm start'

what about '/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -t'? now it doesn't complain about config options?

Comment: I changed 2 lines in my php-fpm.conf this one `pm.min_spare_servers = 1` and this one : `pm.max_spare_servers = 5`

Answer (score -1):

php-fpm does not take "start" "stop" arguments, it is not an init script.
You kill it like this: "killall php-fpm" and you just start it like any simple script: /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm (without the "start" parameter)